# How to test Tabulator table columnMoved event?

Tags: angular, unit-testing, karma-jasmine, tabulator

I have a component with a Tabulator table.
The table listens for *columnMoved* event.
Need to trigger column move so columnMoved() is called.

```
public createTable(div: HTMLDivElement, columnNames: ColumnHeader[], elementRef: ElementRef): void {
    this.table = new Tabulator(div, {
      (...)
      movableColumns: true,
      pagination: 'local',
      paginationSize: this.paginationSize,
      paginationInitialPage: this.currentPage,
      columns: columnNames,
      persistence: {
        sort: true, // persist column sorting
        group: true, // persist row grouping
        page: true, // persist page
        columns: ['width', 'order'],
      },
      columnMoved(column, columns) {
        // does some logic & dispatches a custom event
      },
    });
}
```

Tried many different approaches, e.g.:

```
  describe('createTable', () => {
    it('should dispatch event if columns moved', () => {

      const columnMovedSpy = spyOn(component.table, 'moveColumn');
      component.table.moveColumn("col1", "col2", false);
      expect(columnMovedSpy).toHaveBeenCalled();
      expect(dispatchEvent).toHaveBeenCalled();

    });
  });
```

Above fails at:

```
expect(dispatchEvent).toHaveBeenCalled();
```

And:

```
let submitEl = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('#tableContainer')).nativeElement;
submitEl.triggerEventHandler('columnMoved');
```

Any ideas ?